# SQL Agent Job report omit previously sent data

Tags: sql-server, jobs, sql-server-2008

I posted a similar question to help me with this script and I figured out that main part of it.
It's a simple report setup as a SQL Agent job in SSMS. It sends the results by e-mail as an HTML table in the e-mail body using SP_Send_dbmail. I got it to work so that the report is only sent if there are results from the query.

What I'd like for it to do ontop of this is to omit any rows that were sent in the previous report.
Would this be possible?

This is what my script looks like:

```
if exists(select o.ord_billto, o.ord_refnum , o.ord_hdrnumber, o.mov_number, o.ord_status,  o.ord_cmdvalue, o.ord_startdate
from orderheader o
where ord_billto in ('a','b','c','d')
and DATEDIFF(minute  , o.ord_datetaken, GETDATE())<=7
and ord_cmdvalue >= 250000
and ord_status in ('avl','pln','std','cmp')
)
begin
    declare @tableHTML NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @tableHTML=
    N'<h1>Test Report</h1>'+
    N'<table border=1>'+
    N'<tr><th>Bill To</th>'+
    N'<th>Reference number</th>'+
    N'<th>Order #</th>'+
    N'<th>Move #</th>'+
    N'<th>Order Status</th>'+
    N'<th>Value</th>'+
    N'<th>Ship date</th>'+
    N'<th>Delivery Date</th>'+
cast(( select td=o.ord_billto, '',
    td=o.ord_refnum, '',
    td=o.ord_hdrnumber, '',
    td=o.mov_number, '',
    td=o.ord_status, '',
    td=convert(decimal(10, 2), o.ord_cmdvalue), '',
    td=convert(varchar, o.ord_startdate, 101), '',
    td=convert(varchar, o.ord_completiondate, 101), ''
    from orderheader o
where ord_billto in ('a','b','c','d')
and DATEDIFF(minute , o.ord_datetaken, GETDATE())<=7
and ord_cmdvalue >= 250000
and ord_status in ('avl','pln','std','cmp')
    for XML path('tr'), type
    ) as NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
    N'</table>' ;

    execute msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients='e-mail@domain.com',
    @subject='Test Report',
    @body=@tableHTML,
    @body_format='HTML',
    @attach_query_result_as_file='false',
    @query_attachment_filename='EDI.csv',
    @query_result_separator='',
    @query_result_no_padding='FALSE'
end
```

Comment: Then you need to add a column to `orderheader` indicating the data was already sent, and update/ignore that column in future.

Comment: Is there another way of doing this without affecting the table? This db in question is updated by the application our employees use, and each schema is precisely configured to to work with that application. I was hoping of implementing this within the report script itself if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at an existing script we have that does something similar, and it has this portion of code added at the bottom of the script; Turns out we have 15 extra columns on our orderheader table that's used for "flags"

```html
update orderheader  set ord_extrainfo2=1
where ord_billto in ('A','B','C','D')
and DATEDIFF(MINUTE  , ord_datetaken, GETDATE())<=7
and ord_cmdvalue >= 250000
and ord_status in ('avl','pln','std','cmp')



update orderheader
set ord_extrainfo2=NULL
where ord_billto in ('A','B','C','D')
and DATEDIFF(MINUTE  , ord_datetaken, GETDATE())<=7
and ord_cmdvalue <= 250000
and ord_status in ('avl','pln','std','cmp')
and ord_extrainfo2<>NULL
```

I'll try adding this to the bottom of my script and will update when i get some results.

Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I just realized why i can't use IF ( Select [...]) > 0...

How would i go about using that logic if i have multiple columns i want to include in the script? The example i based this on simply had a COUNT function in the select, and all the rows were declared in the HTML Table part. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well i figured out for my question above that i could simply put a dummy colum for my IF statement so i used count(o.ord_hdrnumber).

The update part of the script is working, but when it comes to resetting the "flag" to null i get an error saying to can't convert the varchar value 'NULL' to an int. The ord_extrainfo2 column is a varchar(30) datatype...

I got another report request using the same logic so i'd like to figre this thing out once and for all :S